# php \n new line no show well

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to show this line to the end when go to submit texarea , for save little data i use txt db and i have problem because the line with \n no get replace this character

For example
:

```
$replace=str_replace("\n","<br>",$val);
$replace=str_replace("\r","<br>",$val);
$replace=str_replace("\n\r","<br>",$val);
```

Replace \n by `<br>` but inside the text no see only line i see this

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5<br>
hello
<br>
yes
<br>
```

And this it´s bad because i need show all in only line

Thank´s Regards !!!

Comment: You are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: No i don´t want use that the data save in txt and i need replace \n

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo It's short, sweet, correct and probably the answer--you should submit it as one. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you try to replace the `\n` by a HTML `<br>` ? If it is, you can use the nl2br function of PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered using:

```
echo nl2br($Val);
```

Which makes your code more graceful than looking at:

```
$replace=str_replace("\n","<br>",$val);
$replace=str_replace("\r","<br>",$val);
$replace=str_replace("\n\r","<br>",$val);
```

as nl2br does exactly what your `str_replace` lines are doing and makes it easier.

This converts all the line break formats to the HTML `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$replace=str_replace("\\\n","<br>",$val);
$replace=str_replace("\\\r","<br>",$val);
$replace=str_replace("\\\n\\\r","<br>",$val);
```

For example, \n sends literal character n. 
However, \\n is interpreted as \ (literal character "\") and \n (literal character "n") or altogether, literal "\n"